# Let the user select how many days of data he wants

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @Days varchar(max)

set @Days = '-7'

select      

dateadd(hour,datepart(hour,Timestamp + GETDATE() - GETUTCDATE()),cast(CAST((Timestamp + GETDATE() - GETUTCDATE()) as date) as datetime)) as [Time]      

from  [Employee]

where dateadd(hour,datepart(hour,Timestamp + GETDATE() - GETUTCDATE()),cast(CAST((Timestamp + GETDATE() - GETUTCDATE()) as date) as datetime)) >= DATEADD(day,' + @Days + ', GETDATE()))
```

I want the user to select the number of days(@Days) of data he wants. So if he wants the data for last 15 days, all he has to do is set @Days = '-15'. Timestamp is the date along with time Column in my Employee table but Timestamp is UTC. I have written the query above and it is returning some data but I am confused if the query is correct or not?

Comment: use datediff to get the difference between UTC and local and store it in a variable.  e.g SET @DIF = DATEDIIF(hour, GETUTCDATE(),GETDATE())

Comment: I would at least declare @Days as an INT.  Since you can't use an INT for hacking via Sql-injection.

Comment: There must be more you're not showing since the query is not valid syntax as written; it looks like it's actually supposed to be part of a dynamically-constructed query, judging by the quotes around `@Days`. I would carefully consider whether you really need dynamic SQL or not; you haven't given enough information for me to be sure. If you do, then take LukStorms' suggestion on the data type, and construct a parameterized query instead of inserting the value of `@Days` directly into the query text.

Comment: You should avoid using reserved words as column names. Timestamp is a datatype and it is way too ambiguous for a column name anyway. Also, don't get in the habit of doing date math like that. You should use DATEADD and DATEDIFF. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Answer (score 1):

I think the following simple query should do the trick.

```
declare @Days INT = -7;   --<-- Use int not varchar

SELECT  *  
FROM  [Employee]
WHERE CAST([Timestamp] AS DATE) >= CAST(DATEADD(day, @Days, GETUTCDATE()) AS DATE);
```

`DATEADD()` function's 2nd parameter is an int, you can pass the variable `@Days` to the function as it is.

Comment: I want the time to be in eastern time not UTC